# How to pick CMYK colors in Adobe Illustrator Paragraph Styles?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, cmyk, paragraph-styles

I'm trying to set CMYK colors to a Paragraph Style on Illustrator CC but it seems impossible to get over the preset colors list, mostly colors in RGB. Is there a way to choose colors I want in CMYK?
[image: Paragraph Style Options pane]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those colors **are** CMYK colors. The name of the swatch may have "RGB" in it, but the color is built as a CMYK color...

Note the color icons on the right... The icons indicate the color build.

[image]

The *name* of the swatch makes *absolutely no difference*. You can easily create CMYK colors and add "RGB" to the name, or create RGB colors and add "CMYK" to the name. The *name* does not change the color build.

In *general*, if your document color mode is set as CMYK, then colors are built on a CMYK model. And conversely if the document color mode is set to RGB then colors are built on the RGB model. It actually takes a couple extra steps to *purposefully* add RGB colors to a CMYK document or vice versa.

If you are seeking to choose a *different* color, then No. The Paragraph Styles dialog box does *not* offer the ability to choose colors via the picker or sliders or "tweak" any existing colors. You need to set up a color swatch *first* then choose that swatch in the Styles Dialog window.

Comment: Thank you! I created new swatches at Swatches tab so the colors appear in the pane. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Fill color, even text fill color or the fill for a paragraph can be set with the color picker window.

[image]

The white square is the fill of a selected object. By double clicking the fill square you open the color picker where you can set color.

[image]

On the right are the CMYK % values.

Once you have your text looking how you want you can apply its styles to a New Paragraph Style.

With the new Paragraph Style window open, select the text and hit the new style button:

[image]

Name it and you are done.